# gVim 8.2 stuck on startup

Tags: vim, windows-10

My gVim 8.2 (Windows 10) always get stuck during startup, showing the window below.

[image: gVim stuck on startup]

Looking at Windows Task Manager, it shows `ctags.exe` consuming ~30% of CPU, and 40MB of RAM.

I have to close it manually (***or wait for 10+ minutes!***), then the program starts...

How can I make it go straight to the program without showing this?

NOTE: Also, my Vim (not gVim) doesn't even show anything (only a black window with a blinking cursor, no matter if I call it from the terminal or not). Both are 64bit, but the same did happen with the 32bit version.

Comment: From your picture, it is calling `ctags`. I don't know where the current folder `.` is. It may take time to finish indexing. And did you open `vim.exe` or `gvim.exe`? I tried `vim.exe`, it's a black window with no GUI element.

Comment: @Light The shortcut targets to `C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a plugin or autocommand in your Vim config that automatically runs ctags. This isn't default behavior.

Comment: Solved! There was a line `call system('ctags -R .')` in my `~/.vimrc` file. Just commented it, and bingo! Thank you very much @orlp

Answer (score 0):

Actually Don't Use The Command Line Version Use The gVim App In Your Laptop/PC

Comment: I'm already doing that. It has nothing to do with the problem.